# Trying to understand odd variant of a PHP array_map() call

Tags: php, array-map

I'm trying to understand some code I found the open source oauth-php library.  The relevant code snippet is:

```
protected function sql_printf ( $args )
{
    $sql  = array_shift($args);
    if (count($args) == 1 && is_array($args[0]))
    {
        $args = $args[0];
    }
    $args = array_map(array($this, 'sql_escape_string'), $args);
    return vsprintf($sql, $args);
}
```

Where $args is an array of arguments that contain variables intended for use in a formatted printing operation.  I looked at the docs for array_map:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

and the user comments and I did not see any use case where the first parameter in a call to array_map() was an array itself.  In all the use cases I saw, the first parameter was either NULL or a (callback) function.  It seems pretty obvious to me that the code takes the $args array and then builds a new array with the arguments sanitized by $this->sql_escape_string().

But the statement "array($this, 'sql_escape_string')" is throwing me since I would have expected simply '$this->sql_escape_string', or is that not a valid syntax?  If so, how does wrapping $this and 'sql_escape_string' in an array create a valid callback function for array_map() to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is actually passing the `sql_escape_string` method from the class itself as a callback. It is a way of clarifying ambiguous method calls. For example:

```
array_map('sql_escape_string', $args);
```

of course applies `sql_escape_string()` to each value in `$args`, whereas:

```
array_map(array($someClass, 'sql_escape_string'), $args);
```

applies the `sql_escape_string()` method **from `$someClass`** to each value in `$args`.

Answer (score 3):

The first parameter is a [callback](https://www.php.net/callback#language.types.callback). It can be either a string or an array.

> since I would have expected simply '$this->sql_escape_string'

You would if it were just one scalar value. But you have an array and you need to apply that escape function to each item of the `$args` array. So you need to implement `foreach` and apply that function or use one-liner with `array_map`.

Answer (score 1):

> But the statement "array($this, 'sql_escape_string')" is throwing me since I would have expected simply '$this->sql_escape_string', or is that not a valid syntax?

It's valid, but doesn't refer to what you think it refers to. Consider free functions, constants, class names and variables: each exists in different environments (or "namespaces" if you prefer, but that's easily confused with [PHP namespaces](http://php.net/namespace)). The different environment for variables is made explicit by the use of "$" as a [sigil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigil_%28computer_programming%29): the variable `$foo` versus the function `foo()`, constant `foo` and class `Foo`. This is also why constants and variables are case-sensitive, but functions and class names aren't: the different environments allow for different name resolution rules.

Similarly, object methods and properties exist in different environments. As a consequence, `$this->sql_escape_string` refers to a property, not a method. To confuse matters, that property could contain a callable, though such a callable couldn't be [invoked directly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2080248/):

```
class Foo {
    function frob() {return 23.0 / 42;}
}

$foo = new Foo;
$foo->frob = function () {return 0 / 0;};

$foo->frob(); # calls method, not closure function

$frob = $foo->frob;
$frob(); # oops: division by zero
```

As with constants and functions, properties and methods are distinguished by the absence or presence of an argument list.

> If so, how does wrapping $this and 'sql_escape_string' in an array create a valid callback function for array_map() to use?

PHP's syntax for [callable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) references goes beyond strings.

Free functions (functions not associated with a class or object; contrast with "bound functions") can unambiguously be referred to by their names. Static methods are bound to a class, but can be referred to with a string if it includes the class name (the syntax is "Class::method"). A string cannot contain enough information for an object method, however, since the method must be bound to a particular object, and PHP doesn't have a way to refer to an object using a string. The solution PHP's developers settled on was to use array syntax (as shown in the question sample code). They also included support for array syntax for static methods (`array('Class', 'method')`).

Besides callable references, callables can be closures. These offer an alternative way of passing object methods, but are more verbose and complex.

```
$self = $this; # workaround: $this not accessible in closures before 5.4
$args = array_map(
    function ($value) use($self) {
        return $self->sql_escape_string($value);
    }, $args);
```

Closures aren't so useful when a callable reference will do, but are more powerful overall.