# Calling class method from string stored as class member

Tags: php, method-call

I am trying to call a method stored as `$_auto`, but it will not work.

```
<?php
    class Index {
        private $_auto;

        public function __construct() {
            $this->_auto = "index";
            $this->_auto();
        }

        public function index() {
            echo "index";
        }
    }

    $index = new Index();
?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lambda Functions in PHP aren't Logical](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080248/lambda-functions-in-php-arent-logical)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`call_user_func`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) to do this:

```
call_user_func(array($this, $this->_auto));
```

Unfortunately PHP does not allow you to directly use property values as [callables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php).

There is also a trick you could use to auto-invoke callables like this. I 'm not sure I would endorse it, but here it is. Add this implementation of `__call` to your class:

```
 public function __call($name, $args)
 {
     if (isset($this->$name) && is_callable($this->$name)) {
         return call_user_func_array($this->$name, $args);
     }
     else {
         throw new \Exception("No such callable $name!");
     }
 }
```

This will allow you to invoke callables, so you can call free functions:

```
 $this->_auto = 'phpinfo';
 $this->_auto();
```

And class methods:

```
 $this->_auto = array($this, 'index');
 $this->_auto();
```

And of course you can customize this behavior by tweaking what `__call` invokes.

Comment: You don't *need* `call_user_func`, you can just wrap the property value in curly braces, i.e. `$this->{$this->_auto}();`, and [PHP will keep on chuggin](http://viper-7.com/bsrn88).

Comment: @nickb: I always succeed in forgetting that syntax. I really must not be liking how it looks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a method named `_auto()`, you only have a property named `$_auto`. If your intent is for a call to an undefined method to return a similarly named property if it exists, then you would need to write a `__call()` magic method to perform the logic of looking at a similarly named property and returning the value.  So something like this would need to be added to your class:

```
public function __call($called_method, $arguments) {
    if(property_exists($this, $called_method)) {
        return $this->{$called_method};
    } else {
        throw new Exception('Illegal method call.');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You code is trying to call a method called "_auto".  To do what you are asking, you want to make the method name a php variable or something along the lines of what the other posters are saying.

```
class Foo {
    private function _auto() {
        echo "index";
    }

    public function callmethod($method) {
        $this->$method();
    }
}

$foo = new Foo();
$foo->callmethod('_auto');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you mistakenly defined "_auto" as a property?

Try using:

```
private function _auto(){}
```

Instead of

```
private $_auto
```